# Do regular expression engine parse characters one by one?

Tags: regex

It is kind of absurd to ask. Anyway, let me proceed.

While exploring the regular expressions, I come across a scenario, where the expression is

```
[A-Z0-9]+(\d\d\.\d+)
```

The input string is **123.456** and the pattern being matched is as follows,

[image]

The pattern `[A-Z0-9]+` could have matched upto **135**, but it is not followed by the 2 more digits (`\d\d`) and a literal dot character. So, engine went with having characters `23.456` in the first subgroup.

Whether the regular expression engine check for the match by parsing one character at a time ? I was in that assumption.

By looking at this, it seems not. The engine should be parsing characters as well moving the window of matching back and forth, so that it can help us matching the result.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What is your expected result? I think the result you get is expected one.

Comment: Take a look at the regex debugger on the site you're using (regex101.com) - it shows the very steps you're asking about.  You can see that initially, it did indeed match `123` using `[A-Z0-9]+`, then had to backtrack.

Comment: Yes, it is expected result only. So, regex engine always backtrack if it had to. Right ?

Comment: If your regex allows multiple ways of matching a string, yes, when there is a fail at some further step, the engine can backtrack if the preceding subpattern(s) allow that (usually, when there is a quantified subpattern, or  lookarounds).

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/2861/regular-expression-engine-types#t=201703100912550017219) :)

Comment: It does go character by character, it just backtracks if the current match attempt failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex engine parse the string according to the pattern it is given.

Your pattern is `[A-Z0-9]+(\d\d\.\d+)`. Given the `123.456` string, the `[A-Z0-9]+` is first tried from the beginning of the string. `123` is grabbed first (since `+` is a greedy quantifier). Then the regex engine tries to match the rest of the string with `(\d\d\.\d+)` - and fails. *Backtracking* occurs because the regex engine knows that `[A-Z0-9]+` can match a different (smaller) portion of the string, and thus, the `3` is dropped from the currently consumed chars, and `(\d\d\.\d+)` is retried to match `3.456`, but there must be 2 digits before  a dot. Backtracking happens again.

Thus, only `1` remains outside the capturing group 1 value.

Also, have a look at the steps generated at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/y3FMW4/1/debugger) (backtracking is marked with [image]):

[image]